# Python MongoDB DateTime isoformat

Tags: python, mongodb

Hi all this is my code:

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient()

a = 1
b = 2
date_stamp = '2016-04-28'
time_stamp = '17:21:34.056'
c = 3

db.tests.test01.update(
    {
        'a': a,
        'b': b,
        'date_time_stamp': ' new Date("' + date_stamp + 'T' + time_stamp  + 'Z' + '")'}, {'$set': { 'a': a, 'b': b,
    'date_time_stamp': ' new Date("' + date_stamp + 'T' + time_stamp + 'Z' + '")',
'c': c}
},
upsert=True)
```

Since I have the date and the time, how can I create an isodate to send to MongoDB?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create any special format for your date. pymongo works with python standard library types and automatically converts them, which means you can use the python standard library [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module for your date/time/datetime.